# Raspberry Pi 2 - Stuck on apt-get (gnome-user-guide)

Tags: download, installation, apt-get, raspberry-pi2

i recently got Raspberry Pi 2 and installed Raspbian Jessie. Everything was working fine but now i can't install almost anything. Everytime it wants to install gnome-user-guide with 0B

`Need to get 0 B/(forgot) MB of archives.`

and

`Preparing to unpack .../gnome-user-guide_3.14.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-user-guide (3.14.1-1) over (3.14.1-1) ...`

I tried almost everything like removing it (force remove) because normal remove wasn't working (saying that this package is wrong and should be reinstalled) and i am desperate.

Thanks.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention i have enough space.

Comment: I *"solved"* it. Just installing things by `apt-get -y install {thing}`...

Comment: still hanging at ¨Unpacking gnome-user-guide (3.14.1-1) over (3.14.1-1¨ for me

Comment: Create an answer by yourself and accept it as answered then , this way the post will be closed! Joseph, I suggest that you create another post, for this one won't have any answer coming I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, this maybe a little late
This error is probably caused because of a corrupted temp package which was interrupted (In dpkg). 
I solved this issue by

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq gnome-user-guide
```